# How to delete saved orged configurations in vs code

Tags: vs-code

How can I delete the org configurations which are saved. They always appear when I try to authorize any org and want to remove some of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

On Windows: you can press windows key + r then type `%USERPROFILE%\.sfdx`.
On Linux and Mac OS: `~/.sfdx`.

In that directory you'll find a json file for each login saved, each one named after your username in that org.
That json holds the following properties:

- `username`
- `orgId`
- `accessToken`
- `refreshToken`
- `instanceUrl`
- `loginUrl`
- `clientId`

You can delete the ones you don't need.